# map and filter is outputting an array of outcomes and not expected value

Tags: javascript

I am a little confused on the output of my variable 'ready' where I was hoping it will take the correct value from the json, which I was expecting to be 'true' but comes back with an array `['false', 'true']` and so it doesn't go into the condition set. Does anyone know what it's displaying an array with possible outcomes and not the value which I expect to be true?

Example JSON

```
{
      "data": {
        "competition": [
          {
            "events": [
              {
                "field": [
                  {
                    "ready": "true",
                    "__typename": "Field"
                  },
                  {
                    "ready": "true",
                    "__typename": "Field"
                  },
                  {
                    "ready": "true",
                    "__typename": "Field"
                  }
                ],
                "__typename": "Event"
              },
              {
                "field": [
                  {
                    "ready": "true",
                    "__typename": "Field"
                  },
                  {
                    "ready": "true",
                    "__typename": "Field"
                  },
                  {
                    "ready": "true",
                    "__typename": "Field"
                  }
                ],
                "__typename": "Event"
              }
            ],
            "__typename": "Competition"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Code:

```
export function dailyListConverter(list) {
      const ready = JSON.parse(list)
        .data.competition[0].events.filter((event) => event.field)
        .map((event) => event.field[0].ready);
      if (ready === "true") {
console.log("I'M HERE")
      }
      console.log("OUTSIDE CONDITIONS")
}
```

Comment: when you have a map function call, it will return a list.

Comment: What is your expected outcome? Do you want to return a list of things or just iterate through nested objects?

Comment: Are you trying to check if all the ready keys in under the arrays events and fields are true? It would be helpful if you stated the reason for your expected outcome

Answer (score 0):

Your variable "ready" contains an array because both the methods (filer, map) you have applied to your JSON list have a return type of array (or a kind of object). So ready will always contain an array and therefore it will not satisfy your given condition.